# Php Ajax foreach loop malfunctions

Tags: php, ajax

Good day.

I am working on a poll where the votes will be displayed using ajax.
Take for instance , I have 3 polls: Poll 1, Poll 2, Poll 3.
You have to click on the link of Poll 1 to show the result of Poll 1 in which the page will not reload because of the ajax.
The result are displayed in percentages.

Here is the snippet.

```
$poll_response = query($con, "SELECT *FROM `responses` WHERE `id` = '{$poll_id}'");
$count_response = rows($poll_response);

if($count_response > 0)
{
    $responses_array = array();

   for($j=1;$j<=$count_response;$j++)
    {
        $fetch = fetch($poll_response);
        $response = $fetch['response'];
        $responses_array[] = $response;
    }

    $responses_values = array_count_values($responses_array);
    $min_value = min($responses_values);


    foreach($responses_values as $value=>$count_value)
    {
    ?>
         <div id='votes'> </div>

       <script type="text/javascript">                                          
         var percent_num,width,min_val;
         var each_count = "<?php echo $count_value;?>";
         var total = "<?php echo $count_response;?>";
        var response = "<?php echo ucfirst($value);?>";
        var min_val = "<?php echo $min_value;?>";

       if(each_count > 0)
       {
            percent_num = ( (each_count *100)/total);
            percent_num = Math.round(percent_num);
            width = percent_num*2;
       }
      else
     {
        width = 1;
       percent_num = 0;
     }

if(total > 0)
{
    var votes = $("#votes");
    votes.html("<table width='50%'><tr><td width='25%'>"+response+"</td><td> &nbsp; &nbsp;<img src='../images/poll_green.jpg' width="+width+" height=20 border=10/> &nbsp;"+percent_num+"% </td><td><span class='badge'>"+each_count+"</span></td><br/></tr></table>");

}
else
{
    document.write("<div class='alert alert-danger'>No result yet</div>");
}

 </script>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
```

The problem with the code above is that it only display one record in the database.
Take for instance, if u click on the link of Poll 1 and Poll 1 goes thus:

Which computer brand is your favourite?
A). HP
B) Dell
C) Acer.
D) Samsung

and 10 people have voted for HP, 4 for Dell , 7 for Acer and 15 for Samsung.

It should display the title of each of the computer brand with the number of votes and percentage for it, meaning that 4 records will be displayed, but instead, it displays only Dell with its number of votes and percentage alone if ajax is used, but it display all the computer brands with the number of votes and percentage normally if PHP is only used

Please, what can be the cause of this and the likely solution?

Thanks

Comment: If your foreach loops runs more then onces, it overwrites the previous results. I still don't understand what is the main problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

I think you aren't adding the values to your response array right here

```
$responses_array[] = $response;
```

I would try incrementing the index.

```
for($j=1;$j<=$count_response;$j++)
    {
        $fetch = fetch($poll_response);
        $response = $fetch['response'];
        $responses_array[j] = $response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$responses_array[j] = $fetch['response'];
```

instead of it

```
$response = $fetch['response'];
$responses_array[] = $response;
```